# Android : Relativelayout background of a row

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

For the below layout of controls, I am using relative layout with 2 linear layouts.
1 Linear Layout for B1 ,B2 and B3 with grey background and 1 Linear Layout for B4, B5 and B6.

I have read that using Linear Layouts inside Relative Layouts slows the rendering.

Any ideas how I can get rid of Linear Layouts? Especially I cannot get the grey background for the Row B1, B2 and B3. Or do you think it should be fine using this way. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

EDIT :

Below is my xml which I just started building and trying to get rid of any child layouts if possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_holo_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" Test Label" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" >
    </ListView>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: include your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your xml, the only way you will be able to accomplish this, is with is with a single relative layout, that contains another LinearLayout containing your row of buttons.

While you are correct, that it is good practice to limit the number of nested layouts (not just linear, but nested layouts of any type).

In this case, to get your row background set, you will need at least a single nested LinearLayout, and this is not a big issue.

Edit: After reviewing your XML, I do think this is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I updated the question with my xml which I am still building. But your explanation seems to be the answer. Will accept it once you review the xml.

Comment: Your XML looks fine really.  Technically, you could move the 3 buttons that are inside linearLayout2 into the parent Relative Layout.  I don't think this is actually necessary though - it is important to note, that you should avoid a deep hierarchy of views (ie. many levels of nesting deep).  Since you have a shallow hierarchy, this looks good.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. I cant up vote as I am new user.